# Arclinux running xfce4 fails to start

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, boot, xfce, fonts

I run archlinux xfce4 with auto-login and auto start. After upgrading today 07-MAY-13 the X fails without leaving a error message in Xorg.0.log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem *may be* related to fonts and vector drawing in linux (cairo).

If you auto-login and autostart like I do, the first thing to do is to stop athe autostart.

In your `~/.bash-profile` if there is a `startxfce4` command, comment it out.

```
#if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]] && ! [[ -e /tmp/.X11-unix/X0 ]] && (( EUID )); then
#  exec nohup startxfce4 > .xlog & vlock
#fi
```

Also check `~/.xinitrc`

You may need to switch to an alternative console and login in as root, or login from a remote computer, or append `systemd.unit=rescue.target` to the kernel parameters inyour bootloader to do this.

When done reboot and enter `startxfce4` after reaching multi-user in boot.

If you see `libpng15.so.15: cannot open shared object file` in the output, you likely have the vector drawing conflict, likely a `cairo` package from `archlinux,org/AUR` ─ installed to configure how your system does fonts..

How to fix?

A relatively easy way is too replace the fonts packages from `archlinux,org/AUR` with a new bundle by archlinux user **bohoomil** in the `archlinux.org/wiki`
as [Infinality: the easy way](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_Configuration#Infinality%3a_the_easy_way)

If you are fussy about how fonts appear on the screen, be sure to read the [form posts](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162098) and the [user](http://bohoomil.github.io/ib.html) notes before you decide to do this.

The wiki covers what you you have to do, but look at these notes beore you start:

1. You will be fundmentaly changing the way your archlinux uses fonts.
2. You will have to add links in `/etc/pacman.conf` to his repository
3. You will likely have to remove some packages from `archlinux,org/AUR` but this will be done as part of the installation.
4. Don't forget multilib if you run x86_64.
5. Don't forget to run `sudo pacman -Syy` after updating 'pacman/conf'
6. You may have to force (`sudo pacman -Sd ⋯`) some package(s) installation.
7. The pacman command for the bundle is `sudo pacman -Syu infinality-bundle`
8. To force install the pacman command is `sudo pacman -Sd infinality-bundle` ⁂ use with care!

Good luck!

As an example, here is my `pacman.log` from this morning…

```
[2013-05-07 11:09] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syu cairo'
[2013-05-07 11:09] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2013-05-07 11:09] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2013-05-07 11:09] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syu cairo'
[2013-05-07 11:09] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2013-05-07 11:09] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2013-05-07 11:10] [PACMAN] removed cairo-cleartype (1.12.2-1)
[2013-05-07 11:10] [PACMAN] installed cairo (1.12.14-4)
[2013-05-07 11:10] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syu infinality-bundle'
[2013-05-07 11:10] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2013-05-07 11:10] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2013-05-07 11:14] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Sd infinality-bundle'
[2013-05-07 11:15] [PACMAN] removed freetype2-infinality (2.4.10-1)
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] 
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   Check for dead symlinks and leftover files 
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   in /etc/fonts/conf.d/
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   
[2013-05-07 11:15] [PACMAN] removed fontconfig (2.10.92-4)
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM] warning: /etc/fonts/conf.d/52-infinality.conf saved as /etc/fonts/conf.d/52-infinality.conf.pacsave
[2013-05-07 11:15] [PACMAN] removed fontconfig-infinality (1-20130104)
[2013-05-07 11:15] [PACMAN] removed cairo (1.12.14-4)
[2013-05-07 11:15] [PACMAN] removed lib32-freetype2 (2.4.11-1)
[2013-05-07 11:15] [PACMAN] removed lib32-fontconfig (2.10.92-1)
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   If you have been using freetype2-infinality from the AUR,
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   the runtime file that came with it has been saved as
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   /etc/profile.d/infinality-settings.sh.pacsave and the new
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   one was installed in its place. You can manually delete
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   infinality-settings.sh.pacsave as it is not needed anymore.
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] 
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   If you are using [multilib], please install/upgrade
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   lib32-freetype2-infinality-ultimate, too.
[2013-05-07 11:15] [PACMAN] installed freetype2-infinality-ultimate (2.4.11-3)
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   Fontconfig-ultimate configuration is done via 
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   /etc/fonts/conf.avail, /etc/fonts/conf.avail.infinality and 
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   conf.d. Read /etc/fonts/conf.d/README for more information.
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] 
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   Configuration via /etc/fonts/local.conf is still possible,
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   but is no longer recommended for options available in conf.avail.
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] 
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   Main systemwide configuration should be done by symlinks, e.g.
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   # cd /etc/fonts/conf.d
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   # ln -s ../conf.avail/XX-foo.conf
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] 
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   In most cases default settings should suffice.
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] 
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   Custom user based configuration should be done in the same way,
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   using XDG directory structure, e.g.
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] 
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   $ cd /root/.config/fontconfig/conf.d
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   $ ln -s ../conf.avail/XX-foo.conf
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] 
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   A few examples can be found in
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]     /usr/share/doc/fontconfig/infinality-ultimate/fontconfig.
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   For further information about fontconfig-infiinality-ultimate, see
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]     /usr/share/doc/fontconfig-infinality-ultimate/README.html
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET]   Check also https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts.
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] 
[2013-05-07 11:15] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] updating font cache... done.
[2013-05-07 11:15] [PACMAN] installed fontconfig-infinality-ultimate (2.10.92-8)
[2013-05-07 11:15] [PACMAN] installed cairo-infinality-ultimate (1.12.14-5)
[2013-05-07 11:15] [PACMAN] installed lib32-freetype2-infinality-ultimate (2.4.11-2)
[2013-05-07 11:15] [PACMAN] installed lib32-fontconfig-infinality-ultimate (2.10.92-2)
[2013-05-07 11:18] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -Syu lib32-freetype2-infinality-ultimate'
[2013-05-07 11:18] [PACMAN] synchronizing package lists
[2013-05-07 11:18] [PACMAN] starting full system upgrade
[2013-05-07 11:18] [PACMAN] reinstalled lib32-freetype2-infinality-ultimate (2.4.11-2)
```